# Expressing custom per-class de/serialization methods in Scala

Tags: json, scala, serialization

I'm building a JSON serialization tool and I want to be able to define custom serialize and deserialize methods on classes in Scala. Unfortunately, though, since Scala doesn't have static methods, I haven't been able to figure out a nice way to express the `fromJSON` method.

What I would like to write is:

```
class Foo(val x: Int) extends Serializable {
  def toJSON = JInteger(x)
  static val fromJSON: PartialFunction[JValue, Foo] = {
    JInteger(x) => new Foo(x)
  }
}
```

... but `static` [doesn't exist](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4581). I could write the static method in a companion object:

```
object Foo {
  val fromJSON: PartialFunction[JValue, Foo] = {
    JInteger(x) => new Foo(x)
  }
}
class Foo(val x: Int) extends Serializable {
  def toJSON = JInteger(x)
}
```

but then the compiler won't check for its presence in every `Serializable` class, and mistakes could creep in at runtime if it accidentally wasn't defined.

I'm new to Scala — what's a good way to express this? I want to write my serialize/deserialize methods in or close to the classes they represent.

Comment: you could imho resort to using implicits or use a JSON library.

Comment: I have looked at all the JSON libraries I could find for Scala. None of them let me define custom de/serializers as simply as I'd like.

Comment: How would the compiler check for a method that doesn't belong to `Serializable` in a `Serializable` class?

Comment: @sourcedelica exactly. i'm looking for a better way to express this that allows it to be checked at compile time.

Comment: that would be using type bounds : def foo[A<:Serializable with SomeOthertrait](entity:A) but that doesnt apply to the companion object.